# discord.js trying to collect number after a button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I want my bot to recognize that if my collection equals to 1 then do something but the bot is not getting if it was 1 here is my code

```
if(button.id === 'policeticket') {

    let member = button.clicker.user.id;

    button.channel.send("type a number")

  const filter = m => m.author.id == button.clicker.user.id;
  button.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(async collection => {
  let number = collection.first(); 
   
  if(number === "1") {
button.channel.send("test")
  
}
  })
                }
              })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't no if is correct, but i think do you are comparate a number with a string, and that's comparate always return false if value was number.

in your case i would try this code.

```
if (button.id === 'policeticket') {

  let member = button.clicker.user.id;

  button.channel.send("type a number")

  const filter = m => m.author.id == button.clicker.user.id;
  button.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(async collection => {
      let number = collection.first();

      if (number === 1) {
        button.channel.send("test")

      }
    })
}
```

Comment: tried and its still not working

Comment: you can show for me all part of this code?

Comment: thats everything we just have the   client.on('clickButton', async button => {

Comment: try put a console.log in your application for see result of yours variables, for example

Comment: let number = collection.first();
console.log(number)
      if (number === 1) {
        button.channel.send("test")

      }

Comment: try this for see result, and try another form to comparate this constant or see other result

Comment: and check if the result was espected

Comment: i got this content: '1', on my console

Comment: also i got bunch of things like my avatar and the channel informations

Comment: try to put your send button out of button.channel.awaitMenssages

Comment: let number;                                                                                                               button.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(async collection => {
      number = collection.first();

    })                                                                                                                                              
      if (number === 1) {
        button.channel.send("test")
      }

Comment: u mean i put button.channel.send(number) outside of awaitMessag?

Comment: try my code above

Comment: it says number is not defined when i put it outside

Comment: interesting, try to search about the events of then and how to manipulate that

Comment: thanks, this worked for me let number = parseInt(collection.first());

Comment: understand, it's that ok because now u passed that's for a number e comparate number, if you can avaible my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if (button.id === 'policeticket') {

  let member = button.clicker.user.id;

  button.channel.send("type a number")

  const filter = m => m.author.id == button.clicker.user.id;
  button.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(async collection => {
      let number = parseInt(collection.first());

      if (number === 1) {
        button.channel.send("test")

      }
    })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.